# Webview inside a recyclerview become blank on scroll up and down

Tags: android, scroll, webview, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a WebView inside a RecyclerView which becomes blank when the user scrolls up and down. It is necessary to touch the webview to load data again.

How can I prevent the WebView from getting blank?

Comment: you should edit your question and show a bit of your code so the community can help you find the problem. you could also provide some printscreens so we can see what is actually happening.

Comment: That's actually a bug. I faced the same problem. For bug link visit [bug link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740544&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=)